# ¿Cómo puedo replicar la última línea en múltiples archivos?

Tags: bash

Necesito duplicar la última línea en cada archivo de una carpeta.

Intenté con:

```
tail -n 1 *.fa >> *.fa
```

Lo cual me da un error de ambigüedad.

Comment: la parte de `tail -n 1 *.fa` es correcta, pero `>> *.fa` es efectivamente ambigua porque estás intentando redirigir a tantos ficheros como cumplan la condición `*.fa`, mientras que las redirecciones solo pueden ir a un único fichero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplemente itera sobre todos los ficheros y realiza el comando que ya tienes:

```
for fichero in *.fa
do
    tail -1 "$fichero" >> "$fichero"
done
```

En una sola línea:

```
for fichero in *.fa; do tail -1 "$fichero" >> $fichero; done
```

Comment: gracias funcionó

Comment: No entiendo por qué haces `tail -1` y luego lo pasas a `tail -n 1`. Es redundante, el primero ya hace lo que querías :)

Comment: Muchas gracias, la verdad estuve a prueba y error en la terminal. Que pena xD

Answer (score 0):

Algo que también puedes hacer es prescindir de los bucles, con sus miles de punto y comas o de la sintáxis que varía según que tipo de consola shell uses, usando xargs:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.fa" | xargs -I {} bash -c "tail -q -n 1 {} >> {}"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`find`, con esos parámetros, lista todos los archivos con extensión .fa dentro de ese nivel del árbol de archivos, luego, con xargs, después de cada coincidencia ejecuta una instancia de bash y se ejecuta tail como command string. Ese command string es el típico tail sólo que suprimiendo los posibles headers.

En la imagen aparece que le agregué el parámetro "-mindepth 1" pero no es necesario debido a la extensión ".fa" ya que, en un uso anterior a ese commando, quería excluir el directorio padre y actual del resultado de `find`.

Comment: La verdad es que me parece una sintaxis más confusa. El uso de un bucle `for` tan simple no varía especialmente entre Shells

Comment: A mi me parece muy clara, de hecho más que la de while. Tal vez porque ya estoy acostumbrado. Aunque afortunadamente la pregunta no era sobre la opción más «limpia», lo cual para mi, abre la puerta a hacer todo tipo de locuras ;)

Comment: Y referente al bucle `for ` y su sintáxis, recientemente encontré esto entre zsh y bash. El comando `for i in {1..3}; do; echo $i; done` funciona perfectamente en zsh pero no en bash, quizás, en otra ocasión investigue sobre ese tema y lo comente.

Comment: ¿En qué versión de Bash no te funciona? Seguramente sea porque pusiste `;` después del `do`. La expresión `for i in {1..3}; do echo "$i"; done` funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Es precisamente el punto de la diferencia que encontré entre bash y zsh, en bash no funciona con el `do; ` y en zsh si. Y la versión de bash que tengo es la 4.3.48